# How to write a self-updating program in Java?

Tags: java, auto-update

How can i make a Java program which can update itself. I make this program for use within small team. I do not need any advanced features. I just need a simple and minimal solution.

Comment: I thing you need to clarify what you mean by self-updating. This is a pretty loaded and ambiguous term.

Comment: Yes: do you mean in effect a program that writes self-executing code or a program that downloads a new version of itself?

Comment: Sorry for that ambiguos term. It just like firefox update feature. It automatically checks updates over internet and update current version.I try to make small utility for my team and distributed it to team. This is normal desktop swing application. I am also continously improving this program but i didn't want to send this program again to everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/) is meant specifically for this. You ship one jnlp file, and java takes care of fetching the newest version from a server.

Apart from that, you can download updated classes and replace them at runtime.

Comment: It should be noted that applications that (repeatedly) load updated classes while running tend to leak permgen memory.  You can avoid the leaks, but it is not straightforward.

Comment: yes, they'd better be restarted every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by self-updating ?

If you mean that it changes its behavior at runtime (which is rare), you could create code that writes java code, compiles it, and loads it from within a running program. I've seen that done.

The more common scenario is to have a core program with plug-ins, where the plug-ins themselves can be updated at runtime. The simplest way to do this is simply to use interfaces for these services and then load instantiations of these types at runtime. However, writing a fully robust plug-in framework is usually reinventing the wheel. There are many existing architectures such as OSGi.